# How to retrieve multiple input names into one variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have a program where the user can enter the names of there three favorite colors. When it is received by the PHP script I need them to be stored in one variable. If the user enters one color then one color is displayed and entered into the .txt file... if three colors are entered than all three colors are entered into the file etc. Is there a way to receive user input from three separate text fields into one variable? I want them to be displayed in 3 separate fields in an html table.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="colors.php">

<p>Enter Your favorite colors
    <br /><input type="text" name="color1" size="20">
    <br /><input type="text" name="color2" size="20">
    <br /><input type="text" name="color3" size="20">
    </p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

PHP

```
<table>
<tr>
 $color= $_POST['color'];
 $fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
  $colors .= "<td>".$color1."</td>";
    $colors .= "<td>".$color2."</td>";
    $colors.= "<td>". $color3 ."</td>";
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should be getting an undefined index notice.

Comment: I am getting undefined index 'color'

Comment: and undefined variables

Comment: Can you offer solutions ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with John's answer.

Comment: When I add the values to my html table, only the third color is being put into the table even though there is a column for three colors. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array notation for the names of your form inputs:

```
<form method="POST" action="colors.php">

<p>Enter Your favorite colors
<br /><input type="text" name="color[]" size="20">
<br /><input type="text" name="color[]" size="20">
<br /><input type="text" name="color[]" size="20">
</p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

In PHP you will then receive an array of values. Just loop through it like you would any array:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
 foreach ($_POST['color'] as $color) {
   echo "<td>".$color."</td>";
 }
</tr>
</table>
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't trust user data and should sanitize and escape it as necessary.

Comment: this works well but how do I get them to be inserted into separate <td> tags in an html table?

Comment: Will modify my question, I apologize.

Comment: It's just an array. Loop through them using `foreach` like you would any array.